# PHP - Dynamic Link Questions

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I was testing displaying page links dynamically with php, and I was able to achieve it using the following code in my index.php:

```
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="index.php?page=about">About</a>
<a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a>
<a href="index.php?page=news">news</a>


<div class="content">
    <?php

        if( !empty($_GET['page']) ) {

            $allPages = scandir('pages', 0);
            unset($allPages[0], $allPages[1]);
            $page = $_GET['page'];

            if( in_array($page . '.inc.php', $allPages) ) {

                include('pages' . '/' . $page . '.inc.php');
            } else {
                echo "page not found";
            }
        } else {
            include('pages' . '/home.inc.php');
        }






    ?>
</div>
```

Attached, you will also find an image of my directory structure.

I have two questions:

1. Since each item in the url displays with a `?page=contact` can I hide this using a .htaccess file?
2. If you were on that main index.php page and attempted to write a index.php/anythingElse I want it to revert back to simply index.php, but every time I attempt to include(index.php) I generate an infinite loop and the page crashes. How can I avoid that?

[image]

Comment: to point 1: where should the webserver know where to redirect you if you leave out the `?page=contact`? It at least would have to be smth like `index/contact`

Comment: Do you absolutely want/need to write your own router? Why not use one of the many existing ones?

Comment: Hi Jeff, not at all. New to PHP so I'm just testing some theories out. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the query string in the url but you can add .htaccess rules to rewrite the url into something prettier. For example, index.php?page=test can become index/test.

```
#redirect /index.php?page=test to /index/test
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page.php\?query=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /page/%1? [L,R]

#rewrite /index/test to /index.php?page=test
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?query=$1 [L]
```